# Not valid Parquet file: AWS Glue Catalog Table doesn't work with Snappy files

Tags: amazon-web-services, parquet, aws-glue, amazon-athena, snappy

Using a configuration identic to the one used in the Terraform example: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/glue_catalog_table

```
resource "aws_glue_catalog_table" "aws_glue_catalog_table" {
  name          = "MyCatalogTable"
  database_name = "MyCatalogDatabase"

  table_type = "EXTERNAL_TABLE"

  parameters = {
    EXTERNAL              = "TRUE"
    "parquet.compression" = "SNAPPY"
  }

  storage_descriptor {
    location      = "s3://my-bucket/event-streams/my-stream"
    input_format  = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat"
    output_format = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat"

    ser_de_info {
      name                  = "my-stream"
      serialization_library = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe"

      parameters = {
        "serialization.format" = 1
      }
    }

  }
}
```

and then trying to run a simple Athena query on the created table fails with the error

> Not valid Parquet file

I've used every SerDe definition available: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/supported-serdes.html
And all the input_formats I could find, and nothing works.

Trying it with a Parquet file instead of a Snappy file does seem to work, but that doesn't fit my needs. Anyone ever had this working with Snappy files?

Comment: I just ran this https://github.com/prabhacloud/terraform-aws/blob/master/main.tf and was able to read snappy compressed file https://github.com/prabhacloud/terraform-aws/blob/master/test_comp.parquet%20(1).snappy . If this is not working can you confirm how did you compressed your parquet file?

Comment: Your configuration works with your file, not with mine. Mine is being compressed with Firehose with Snappy for S3 Compression.

Comment: Can you upload a sample parquet of yours to some public repo and share it here ? try Github or any other repo

Comment: the file that you attaches is not a parquet file and it is a CSV file. You should use different serde. Let me write an answer.

Comment: what's the delimiter you have ?

Comment: Also how are you writing data to this CSV via firehose. Looks like the CSV is not readable via Athena/SPARK/Glue. Can you try writing with out compression to see if it is a valid CSV ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [compressed flag](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/glue_catalog_table#compressed), since the Parquet files are compressed with Snappy.

Comment: Sadly the same error persists. Added:

storage_descriptor {
    compressed = true
   ...

Comment: parameters in template already have compression enabled